# IIS rewrite rule using regex

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite my urls in the following fashion:

`myapp/green?item=something&item2=nothing&etc...`

needs to be rewritten to lose the "/" after myapp and reorder as below with the addition of the "color"

`myapp?color=green&item=something&item2=nothing&etc.....`

Anybody know how to make a regex pattern to catch and rewrite this in IIS?

What would be even better if I could catch everything after `/` to `?` so that if the link was `myapp/blue?` it would still catch and and rewrite it as `myapp?color=blue`

Answer (score 0):

On the app level in IIS create a blank rule with the following parameters:

Pattern:

```
\/([a-z]*)([\?])
```

Rewrite URL:

```
?color={R:1}
```

EDIT: this is valid if you're passing only this one query string, but if there are more it's best to bind your regex to one of those queries.

see example in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60445496/12969034)