# IIS: Rewrite URL with regex but keep query strings

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

I'm have the following link

`https://example.com/myapp/green?&lang=en&instance=some%20instance`

I need to rewrite it to the following link

`https://example.com/myapp?color=green&lang=en&instance=some%20instance`

The color in the link can be any color but it needs to be rewritten like in the 2nd link so that the trailing slash is replaced with a `?` followed by the word `color=` and the `?` at the end of the color word needs to be removed.

`/myapp/green?` becomes `/myapp?color=green`,

`/myapp/blue?` becomes `/myapp?color=blue`

and so forth, all while keeping the rest of the query string `&lang=en&instance=some%20instance` intact

I've tried regexing my way out of this but I usually catch everything or unintentionally omit the rest of the query string.

Any ideas on what's the best approach?

EDIT: noticed that IIS, when applying to application level (not website level), the input URL path is after '/myapp/' and I need that trailing slash removed. Does this mean I'll have to apply it to the website level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use below url rewrite rule(add this rule at site level):

```
<rule name="color query" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="myapp/(.*)/$" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="lang=(.*)&amp;instance=(.*)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.sample1.com/myapp?color={R:1}&amp;lang={C:1}&amp;instance={C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```

[image]

Note: you could not remove the myapp/ from URL it will be added automatically in URL.